# Using DateBox plugin without "set date" button

Tags: jquery, web-applications, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile with the DateBox plugin.  I only want to show the date picker without the text field.  I did this by using '"useInlineHideInput": true' in the options.  However, I don't want the user to have to click the "Set Date" button.  I disabled it, but when I try to get the value from the field I naturally get an empty string.  Is there a way to get the date from the date picker without having to use the set date button?